# Combine DetailView and SingleTableView in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-tables2

How can I display a SingleTableView table together with a DetailView in django?  What I want is to include or combine both into one. So that when calling DeviceDetailView i receive the device's details and a table of the devices's data (stored also in another model).

I am using django-tables2 for the table.

Someone any idea?

Thank you

```
class DataListView(SingleTableView):
    model = Data
    template_name = 'data/list.html'
    table_class = DataTable

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        queryset = request.POST

        for i in queryset['list'].split(","):

            if queryset['action'] == 'delete':
                Data.objects.filter(data_id=i).delete()


        return HttpResponseRedirect('/data/')


class DeviceDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'devices/detail.html'

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Device, id=id_)
```

**EDIT**
I know it should look something like this:

```
class DeviceDetailView(SingleTableView, DetailView):
    template_name = "devices/device-detail.html"
    model = Device
    table_class = DeviceTable

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        obj = Device.objects.filter(id=id_)
        context['object'] = obj
        return context
```

But i think i still don't know how to do this part inside **get_context_data** so that the elements are merged together...

**SOLUTION**

Ok it is donde like this:

```
class DeviceDetailView(SingleTableView, DetailView):
    template_name = 'devices/device-detail.html'
    model = Data
    table_class = DataTable
    #crumbs = [('Device detail', 'DeviceDetailView')]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        context = super(DetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        table = self.get_table(**self.get_table_kwargs())
        context[self.get_context_table_name(table)] = table
        return context

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Device, id=id_)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can serve the table within your `DetailsView` using custom `get_context_data`. You can render your table in the template as you usually do with `{% render_table table %}`.

```
# import YourModel
# import YourTable

class DeviceDetailView(DetailView):
    model = YourModel
    template_name = 'devices/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        table = YourTable(YourModel.objects.all()) # define your tables data here
        context = {"table": table}
        return super().get_context_data(**context)
```

Comment: Thank you marco for the answer but where put i the SingleTableView class?

Comment: Since you want to expose both (detail and table) in one view there is no need to define two views. Either merge the table in the DetailView (mentioned solution) or send the detail data within the SingleTableView.